# Synchronized and withContext

Tags: kotlin, synchronized, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following class:

```
class SdkWrapper(private val sdk: Sdk) {

    private var inited = false

    suspend fun doSomething() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        if (inited.not()) init()
        useSdk()
    }
        
    private fun init() {
        // takes a long time
        sdk.init()
        inited = true
    }

    // has to be done asynchronously
    // sdk.init() has to have been called before using this
    private fun useSdk() {

    }

}

class Sdk {
    // must only be done once
    fun init() {}
}
```

Before I can do `useSdk()`, I must call `sdk.init()`, but `sdk.init()` must only be called once, not more.

With my current solution, if `doSomething` is called twice quickly (the second time happening while `sdk.init()` still running), I would call `sdk.init()` twice, because `inited: Boolean` is still `false`.

If I move the assignment of `inited` up like:

```
private fun init() {
    inited = true
    sdk.init()
}
```

and `doSomething()` is called twice rapidly, the second call would use the sdk before its' `init()` has been done.

I tried to solve this with:

```
suspend fun doSomething() = synchronized(this){
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        if (inited.not()) init()
        useSdk()
    }
}
```

but receive an error in IntelliJ:

> the withContext suspension point is inside a critical section

I assume that `synchronized` wouldn't work here anyway, because we move off the main thread and `doSomething()` is completed while the `withContext` block is still running?

How can I solve the problem at hand which basically is: `doSomething()` should only run once at a time?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of `synchronized {...}` you can use a Mutex:

```
class SdkWrapper(private val sdk: Sdk) {

    ...

    private val mutex = Mutex()

    suspend fun doSomething() = mutex.withLock {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            if (inited.not()) init()
            useSdk()
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

You can take a look at the official documentation about Coroutines and mutual exclusion [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html#mutual-exclusion).