# Does @Synchronized or synchronized Keyword(s) Work on Kotlin Coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions

From some other [StackOverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64278321), seems mutex is needed if you need to guard a property or function from concurrent coroutine execution. However, I happened to look at the source code of [StateFlow.kt](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/StateFlow.kt#L159-L167) today and noticed:

> This property is **thread-safe** and can be safely updated from concurrent coroutines without external synchronization.

Looking further into the implementation, all it has are [a few traditional *synchronized* blocks](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/StateFlow.kt#L315-L364) without mutexes.

So the question is, does @Synchronized or synchronized keyword(s) work on Kotlin coroutines? The forum discussions mostly indicate they do not, but the official StateFlow implementation suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They work, but Mutex's should be preferred because they can suspend, which avoids blocking a thread the way `synchronized` would.

To make something truly thread-safe, such as StateFlow's `value` property, which can be set from any thread inside or outside of a coroutine, traditional synchronization is required.

Comment: "If a function or property is accessed solely from coroutines, then it does not need traditional synchronization."  I don't think this is right.  Coroutines running on different threads can cause race conditions, can't they?  Even separate coroutines running in the same multi-thread dispatcher can run on different threads.

Comment: @NovaDenizen You're absolutely right. I can't remember why I would have written that. Maybe I was thinking about how properties don't have to be marked volatile if accessed solely from the same coroutine multiple times because of the happens-before guarantee.